# Return value from Runnuble android

Tags: android

I have two threads threadA and main Thread (UI thread), I am posting a runnuble from threadA in main Thread, but I need to get the result back. I solve the problem like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyView myView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        myView = findViewById(R.id.myview);

        Thread threadA = new Thread(() ->{
            //do work
            String res = getPos();
            //do another work
        }); threadA.start();
    }

    private String getPos() {
        AtomicReference<String> res = new AtomicReference<>();
        myView.post(() -> {
            res.set(myView.getPos());
        });

        //wait until the result will be ready
        while (res.get() == null){}
        return res.get();
    }
}
```

This solution works great! But I don't know if it's OK to wait in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a listener would be a better approach,

Create a listener like

```
public interface Listener<T> {
    void on(T arg);
}
```

and use this to get the returned value

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The real problem is that the Android Handler class doesn't offer any listeners, so when the task is done it is automatically triggered and you can't add this listener because you don't have the Handler class, so for example if the Button class doesn't give you the setOnClickListener () method, you can't create one yourself.